# Associate NSG to Subnets in foreach loop Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I've created a small script which creates subnets, I can then pass them through a loop and create network security groups (nsg) with the name of the subnet + -nsg, but when I try to associate the nsg to the subnet it fails saying the nsg doesn't exist. So i created two small scripts and split the create nsg from the associate nsg, but again same error.

Error:

```
 Set-AzureNetworkSecurityGroupToSubnet : ResourceNotFound : The Network Security Group nsg-test-nsg does not exist.
```

But this does definitely exist.

The code I have is:

```
$resource = "rg-subnets"
$vnetName = "vnet-bmg"
$loc = "West Europe"

$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resource -Name $vnetName
$sub = (Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork $vnet).name 

foreach ($subnet in $sub){

 New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $subnet-nsg -ResourceGroupName $resource -Location $loc -Force
 Set-AzureNetworkSecurityGroupToSubnet -Name $subnet-nsg -VirtualNetworkName $vnetName -SubnetName $subnet

}
```

Help! :)

Comment: Did you assign "nsg-test-nsg" to $subnet-nsg?

Comment: Shouldn't you be quoting the `-Name` property? `"$subnet-nsg"`

Comment: @AkiyoshiTsuchida during the loop it uses the curent created nsg with the name $subnet-nsg, during this process it was running on nsg-test-nsg, hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Theo Hi Theo, I tried with and without quotes, and as the `New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $subnet-nsg` didn't require quotes, I assumed the `Set-AzureNetworkSecurityGroupToSubnet -Name $subnet-nsg ` wouldn't require quotes either.

Comment: This worked for me, just add the below into the foreach loop `New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $subnet-nsg -ResourceGroupName $resource -Location $loc -Force
$subnetName = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork $vnet -Name $subnet
$nsg = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $resource -Name "$subnet-nsg"
$subnetName.NetworkSecurityGroup = $nsg
Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -VirtualNetwork $vnet -Verbose`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me,

```
$resource = "rg-subnets"
$vnetName = "vnet-bmg"
$loc = "West Europe"

$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resource -Name $vnetName
$sub = (Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork $vnet).name 

foreach ($subnet in $sub){
New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $subnet-nsg -ResourceGroupName $resource -Location $loc -Force
$subnetName = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -VirtualNetwork $vnet -Name $subnet
$nsg = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $resource -Name "$subnet-nsg"
$subnetName.NetworkSecurityGroup = $nsg
Set-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -VirtualNetwork $vnet -Verbose
}
```